# Redrawing a google chart for every modal pop up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-visualization

Some of the answers on similar queries to this say that you can only call `.load` once.

So this is my bit of code.
It only draws the graph for the first modal.

I need it to redraw the graph with the new information when I open subsequent modals.

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(load_page_data, true);

function load_page_data(){
  $(function(){
    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (){
      rid = $(this).prop('id') ;
      console.log(rid);

      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback',
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(){
          google.load('visualization', '1',{
            packages:['corechart'],
            'callback' : function(){

              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'getdata.php',
                data:{'id': rid},
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                if(data){
                  chart_data = data;
                  drawChart(chart_data, "My Chart", "Data");
                }
                },
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });

      //something end
    });
  });
}


function drawChart(chart_data, chart1_main_title, chart1_vaxis_title){
  var chart1_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(chart_data);
  var chart1_options ={
    title: chart1_main_title,
    vAxis:{
      title: chart1_vaxis_title,
      titleTextStyle:{
        color: 'red'}
    }
  };

  var chart1_chart = new google.visualization.BarChart

  (document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart1_chart.draw(chart1_data, chart1_options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `load` statement only needs to be called once per page

once the `callback` fires the first time,
you can draw as many charts as needed

recommend loading google first, before anything else

if you have `$(document).ready` somewhere, don't need it

you can rely on google's callback to know when the page is ready

recommend set up similar to following...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: load_page_data,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function load_page_data(){
  $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
      rid = $(this).prop('id') ;
      console.log(rid);
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'getdata.php',
          data: {'id': rid},
          async: false,
          success: function(data){
              if(data){
                  chart_data = data;
                  drawChart(chart_data, "My Chart", "Data");
              }
          },
      });
  });
}

function drawChart(chart_data, chart1_main_title, chart1_vaxis_title) {
  var chart1_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(chart_data);
  var chart1_options = {
    title: chart1_main_title,
    vAxis: {title: chart1_vaxis_title,  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
  };

  var chart1_chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart1_chart.draw(chart1_data, chart1_options);
}
```

---

note: you want to use the gstatic loader...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

**not** `jsapi`

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

Comment: Nah man. Unfortunately, it didn't work :(
It still draws the graph only for the first modal and not the subsequent modals.

Comment: Nope. Just this warning :  [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: can you verify `drawChart` is being called? add a `console.log` statement or something...

Comment: Yup. It's being called.

Comment: if it's being called and there are no errors, the chart should be drawn -- there must be something else going on, where is the `chart_div` located, on the modal? is it possible there are multiple containers with the same id? what is the result of --> `$('#chart_div').length` -- if you add a listener to the chart's `'ready'` event, does it get called?

Comment: so I was able solve it. The problem was with the id of the div where the chart was being called. ID's are supposed to be unique, so even though the modal ID was unique, it was always going to call it only for the first modal chart id div ie. chart_data. 
The chart data id needed to be unique too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help :)